# CSS - trying to apply background-image, using ~/ not working

Tags: css, blogengine.net

I'm trying to apply a background-image to a header in a site.master file. If I use:

```
background-image:url('./themes/Modern/images/bg_full.png')
```

It works fine for all root level pages, but for any dynamic pages higher up directory structure it does not apply. So I changed it to:

```
background-image:url('~/themes/Modern/images/bg_full.png')
```

But when I do this the image does not show on any of the pages. Any help appreciated.

Comment: what if you try `background-image:url('../themes/Modern/images/bg_full.png')`

Comment: ~ is a .net server-side construct, it wont work like that in a .css file. if you must use that it will need to go in server-side block. what's you platform? as you are asking for root, does background-image:url('/themes/Modern/images/bg_full.png') not work?

Comment: Hi I am using blogengine.net

Comment: Just remove the `.` or `~`, no need for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS is client based. Basically what your code does is creating a GET request like: `http://domain.com/css/~/themes/Modern/images/bg_full.png`

You probably want something like:

`background-image:url('/themes/Modern/images/bg_full.png');` since this will result in a request like `http://domain.com/themes/Modern/images/bg_full.png`

Answer (score 0):

```
background-image:url('http://your-domain-host.com/path_to_images/bg_full.png');
```

try it if not working then give me your page url i will give you exact code